# Cassandra error: `DriverException: Failed decoding result column "starttime" of type time`

Tags: c++, cassandra, migration

I have a table with column `starttime` having type `time`. Wrongly the client code (c++) inserted some data as `string` for that column. Now when I run `select * from table1;` I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.3\bin\\cqlsh.py", line 1050, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.3\bin\..\lib\cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip\cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b\cassandra\cluster.py", line 3925, i
n result
    raise self._final_exception
DriverException: Failed decoding result column "starttime" of type time: value must be less than number of nanoseconds in a day (86400000000000)
```

Is there a way to get that data so I can create a new table with correct column type and manually insert the data there?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to dump the contents of the SSTable(s) with `sstabledump` and see if you can recover it from there. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately  `sstabledump`  requires to stop `cassandra` which is not acceptable. I will do a live migration from old table to new.

Comment: Actually, there's no reason why you couldn't copy the SSTable to another server and dump its contents out there. 